# schedule a pipeline of azure data lake store which runs on every Monday at 8 am UTC

Tags: azure-data-lake, data-lake

Output Data Set:
`"availability": {"frequency": "Day","interval": 1,"offset": "03:00:00","style": "StartOfInterval"}`

Pipeline:
`"scheduler": {"frequency": "Day","interval": 1,"offset": "03:00:00","style": "StartOfInterval"}`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick

```
{
    "name": "trigger10",
    "properties": {
        "runtimeState": "Stopped",
        "type": "ScheduleTrigger",
        "typeProperties": {
            "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Week",
                "interval": 1,
                "startTime": "2019-02-27T12:49:00.000Z",
                "timeZone": "UTC",
                "schedule": {
                    "minutes": [
                        0
                    ],
                    "hours": [
                        20
                    ],
                    "weekDays": [
                        "Monday"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```